# Html/Php Form Bug

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using php, Apache server
IDK why this weird bug is happening to me
for example the code is ->

```html
<form>
form elements,abc
</form>
extra stuff
```

so the browser is getting the code as

```html
<form>
form elemnts,abc
extra stuff
</form>
```

this was just the example the real code is a bit more complex than this

even if I put the form end above the extra stuff
the browser puts the form at the end of the code again
any solutions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  <title>Artificial Doctor</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #073B4C;
    }

    .heading {
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body><?php require('components/header.php') ?>
  <div class="pt-6 sm:pt-8 lg:pt-12">
    <div class="max-w-screen-2xl px-4 md:px-8 mx-autoflex">
      <h2 class="heading text-2xl lg:text-3xl font-bold text-center mb-4 md:mb-8">LOGIN</h2>
      <form class="max-w-lg border rounded-lg mx-auto" style="margin-bottom: 150px;" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 p-4 md:p-8 bg-white">
          <div>
            <label for="email" class="inline-block text-gray-800 text-sm sm:text-base mb-2">Email</label>
            <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Username OR example@email.com" class="w-full bg-gray-50 text-gray-800 border focus:ring ring-indigo-300 rounded outline-none transition duration-100 px-3 py-2" />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label for="password" class="inline-block text-gray-800 text-sm sm:text-base mb-2">Password</label>
            <input name="password" autocomplete="off" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD@123" type=password class="w-full bg-gray-50 text-gray-800 border focus:ring ring-indigo-300 rounded outline-none transition duration-100 px-3 py-2" />
          </div>
          <div class="m-auto">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="remember_me" name="remember_me">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="remember_me">Remember Me</label>
          </div>

          <button class="block bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-600 focus-visible:ring ring-gray-300 text-white text-sm md:text-base font-bold text-center rounded-lg outline-none transition duration-100 px-8 py-3" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>

      <div class="flex justify-center items-center relative">
        <span class="h-px bg-gray-300 absolute inset-x-0"></span>
        <span class="bg-white text-gray-400 text-sm relative px-4"></span>
      </div>
      <button id="register" class="flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 active:bg-blue-700 focus-visible:ring ring-blue-300 text-white text-sm md:text-base font-semibold text-center rounded-lg outline-none transition duration-100 gap-2 px-8 py-3" onclick="window.location.href ='http://localhost/doctor/register' ">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">how_to_reg</span>Register
      </button>

      <button class="flex justify-center items-center bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 active:bg-blue-700 focus-visible:ring ring-blue-300 text-white text-sm md:text-base font-semibold text-center rounded-lg outline-none transition duration-100 gap-2 px-8 py-3">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">password</span>Forgot Password
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php require('components/footer.php') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw I am sorry I forgot to mention that due to this bug 
my register and forgot password buttons are not working*
I just  wanna fix those register and forgot password buttons

Comment: Input for email has no type. Buttons for register & submit are outside of form.

Comment: `<div class="flex flex-col gap-4 p-4 md:p-8 bg-white">` is opened in `<form>...</form>`, but not closed. So browsers rearrange the content.

Comment: what does the rendered HTML show ( ie: view source )?

Comment: Stack Overflow pages do not append SOLVED to titles to indicate resolution.

Comment: Either delete your question or post an answer yourself and accept it.  If your question is a duplicate, this community will eventially close the page.